# Vue: change data, execute method when animation transform ends, animation transform end listener

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I have this simple `Vue` example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-haze-cstnc2?file=/src/App.vue

[image]

When I click on the box it changes color and scales to 200% of its original size - the scaling takes 3 seconds to complete.

[image]

How do I make the box turn green after the scaling animation is completed, using `Vue`?

```html
<template>
  <div id="container">
    <div
      id="box"
      v-on:click.stop="this.clickAction"
      :class="this.isClicked ? ' changed' : ''"
    ></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},

  data() {
    return {
      isClicked: false,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    clickAction() {
      console.log("click");
      this.isClicked = true;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#box {
  background-color: brown;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 2em;

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#box:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 80%;
}

.changed {
  background-color: cyan !important;

  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 3s;

  transform: scale(2);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set names of the classes instead boolean value in `isClicked` and use setTimeout function to wait 3 secons:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      isClicked: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clickAction() {
      this.isClicked = 'changed';
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isClicked = 'stoped';
      }, 3000)
    },
  },
})
```

```css
#container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#box {
  background-color: brown;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 2em;

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#box:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 80%;
}

.changed {
  background-color: cyan !important;

  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 3s;

  transform: scale(2);
}
.stoped {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div id="container">
    <div
      id="box"
      v-on:click.stop="clickAction"
      :class="isClicked"
    ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or You can use ref and listen to transitioned event:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      isClicked: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clickAction() {
      this.isClicked = 'changed';
      const elem = this.$refs.box;
      elem.addEventListener('transitionend', event => {
        if (event.target === event.currentTarget) {
          this.isClicked = 'stoped';
        }
      });
    },
  },
})
```

```css
#container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#box {
  background-color: brown;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 2em;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#box:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 80%;
}
.changed {
  background-color: cyan !important;
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 3s;
  transform: scale(2);
}
.stoped {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div id="container">
    <div
      ref="box"
      id="box"
      @click="clickAction"
      :class="isClicked"
    ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `setTimeout` the only way? I was hoping there is some kind of a hook

Comment: @parsecer hey mate, You can also use transitioned event and ref. I updated my answer so please take a look :) cheers